# Obj-C NSURLConnection not working

Tags: objective-c, webservice-client

So i am trying to send data to a webservice via url with a parameter. the code i have is below but it never hits the server. the request and responses are null. What am i doing wrong?

```
-(void) postData:(NSString *)data{

NSURLResponse* response;
NSError* error = nil;
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://someaddress.com/api?data=%@", data];

NSURL *lookupURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

//Create the request.
NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:lookupURL];

NSData *request = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];

NSString *dataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:request encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"-----------------------------");
NSLog(@"Request: %@", theRequest);
NSLog(@"req response: %@", request);
NSLog(@"response: %@", dataString);}
```

Comment: please change the title as it is working

Comment: BUT your code is doing a GET no post + you dont encode the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want to POST some binary data but you do a GET request and try to put the binary into the url. (without encoding it)

sample post:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://server.com"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
request.HTTPBody = postData;
NSData *respData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
```

also, note that the synchronous get is bad as it blocks :) use async networking!